# How to set order by parameter that is a table column c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to pass the stored procedure a value for the Order By clause in the behind code of my asp site. I every time I try to pass it a value that is in the db I get the following error: In correct syntax near Product. Product is a value in the db I want to order by. How can I pass this or any other db value to be sorted by to my stored procedure?

```
return App_Code.DBHelper.executeDataSetSP(App_Code.DBHelper.getConnection(), "GetOrderDataByDate", 
                                             new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@start", StartDate),
                                                                  new SqlParameter("@end", EndDate),
                                                                  new SqlParameter("@OrderBy", "Product") }).Tables[0];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Order By" using a parameter for the column name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844678/order-by-using-a-parameter-for-the-column-name)

Comment: @hatchet I need the c# aspect not SQL.

Comment: @GrantWinney no it's a stored procedure and I would have to check not sure if I can.

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos - I think your problem may be in the stored procedure, not how you're calling it. Can you show us at least the `ORDER BY` portion of your stored procedure?

Comment: @hatchet Ah I didn't make I will have him look at him.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer by dave here [Dynamic Sorting within SQL Stored Procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149380/dynamic-sorting-within-sql-stored-procedures) answers your question.

```
    SELECT
       name_last,
       name_first,
       CASE @sortCol WHEN 'name_last' THEN [name_last] ELSE 0 END as mySort
    FROM
       table
    ORDER BY 
        mySort
```