# Add dynamic orderby and ordertype in stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am making an SP which is working fine until I add dynamic order by and ordertype clause

Here is what I am doing

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[master] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @search varchar(255),
    @orderby varchar(50) = 'max(etime)',
    @orderType varchar(10) = 'desc'
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    select count(id) as id,template,[message], [type], line 
    from dbo.pages 
    where template like '%' + @search + '%'  or message like '%' + @search + '%' 
    group by id, template,[message], [type], line 
    order by @orderby @orderType -  error happening on this line
```

It seems in the `order by` clause I am not able to fix it and I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: You *probably* don't need dynamic SQL for this, just order by case expressions of possible `@Orderby` values

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Order By" using a parameter for the column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844678/order-by-using-a-parameter-for-the-column-name)

Comment: 1.  your stored procedure name is HORRIBLE.  please do not use it.  2.  What is calling your stored procedure?  C#?  Java?  Consider ORDERING in the "middle-tier" layer (in the c#, in the java), instead of making the database do that work. Again "consider".  3.  While a dynamic-sql will work....entering the dark maintenance nightmare world of dynamic sql... for some "ordering"....scares me.  4.  The link Stu gave is a decent compromise.  You pass down magic-flags to the stored procedure to "invoke" non-dynamic-sql.

Answer (score -1):

Please reconsider the name of your proc. [dbo].[master] (as a former DBA) just made me weep a little.

You seem to want to parse the value of your parameters into your query, rather than the parameters themselves. If you need to do that, you typically need to use some form of dynamic SQL to achieve that (though there are tricks and ways to work around that).

I.e. something along the lines of:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @sql = 'select count(id) as id,template,[message], [type], line 
    from dbo.pages 
    where template like ''%'' + @searchinput + ''%''  or message like ''%'' + @searchinput + ''%''
    group by id, template, [message], [type], line 
    order by ' + @orderbyinput + ', ' + @ordertypeinput

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@searchinput varchar(255), @search, @orderbyinput varchar(50), @orderby, ordertypeinput varchar(10), @ordertype
```

(This is pseudo code, and I might have added a quote too many or few).

The first line declares a string variable which will contain the code we will want to execute. In the next few lines we use your initial query. The extra quotes are to "escape" the quote used for the wildcard search. We then append the value of @search, and continue the query, and repeat this for the values of @orderby and @ordertype.

Comment: The injection potential of this solution terrifies me.

Comment: @Larnu - Oh, I agree with you on that part. I certainly hope this the procedure is used within the context of other procedures. I do this a lot when generating procedures with dynamic SQL and thus calling things from an external application didn't immediately strike me as a major concern. But you're absolutely right.

Comment: @SchmitzIT why there is extra searchinput in the executesql, i have already declared those variables at top

Comment: i also tried adding the condition `IF (@search = 0) 
  begin 
    1=1
  end
 else 
  begin
   template like '%' + @search + '%'  or message like '%' + @search + '%' 
  end
 end` but its giving me an error

Comment: @Rodney - You added `@search`. `@searchinput` references that, and protects you agaainst SQL injection (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dynamic-sql-query-injection-and-its-prevention-mechanism/#:~:text=Dynamic%20SQL%20Query%20injection%20prevention,to%20process%20the%20SQL%20query.)

Comment: @Rodney `0` is not the same as `NULL` (which, being Dutch confused the hell out of me because the Dutch word for `0` is `nul`, which is too similar to `null`). What is the error you got, and where did you add that particular condition, exactly? You certainly could do a string append (I.e. SET @SQL = 'code here', next line SET @sql += 'more code'. However, if you are calling this from a frontend, I'd add the validation there.